# The target file "D:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\testing\dest" is a directory, not a file.

Tags: c#, file

i have a problem when i try to get some files from a dirrectory it selects the dirrectory and gives me an error:

> The target file "D:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\testing\dest" is a directory, not a file. c#

( i am giving the program only the path that i copy from the file explorer)

The code:

```
 string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(src, "*.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.Length; i++)
        {
            File.Copy(fileArray[i], dst);
        }
```

Comment: it is a string variuble that contains the sorce directory that i want to copy from

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide example inputs and outputs for your program when you post a question to Stack Overflow. This means telling us what the exact value of `src` and `dst` are. We can infer it's a string, but this error has to do with the contents of those variables so it's important for you to tell us what they are.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

File.Copy expects as destination a file name, not a folder name.

Change to this:

```
File.Copy(fileArray[i], Path.Combine(dst, Path.GetFileName(fileArray[i]));
```